# NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFound in test

Tags: maven, junit, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

Hi i have a structure something like this.

```
parent.pom
|-alpha.pom
|-beta.pom
```

in beta i have a dependency towards alpha and in betas test i have a reference to a class in alpha's src/test/java

However it seems when I run the beta test it cannot find the file in alpha.

The class itself is implementing a file from `src/main/java`, so it is something like `FooBarFactoryForTest implements FooBarFactory`. And it cannot find FooBarFactoryForTest when i do `new FooBarFactoryForTest()` in beta's test

Also the same structure works in tests in alpha.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the test classes are not packaged by default in any project, let alone your `alpha` project. It would probably work in your eclipse if you have turned on the workspace resolution feature.

To make it work with `Maven`, consider creating a test jar containing only of test classes in `alpha` and adding as a dependency in `beta`.

Read: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

> You can produce a jar which will include your test classes and
>   resources.
>
> ```
> <project>
>   ...   
>   <build>
>     <plugins>
>       ...
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.6</version>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>             <goals>
>               <goal>test-jar</goal>
>             </goals>
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>       </plugin>
>       ...
>     </plugins>
>   </build>   
>   ... 
> </project>
> ```
>
> To reuse this artifact in an other project, you must declare this
>   dependency with type test-jar :
>
> ```
> <project>   
>   ...   
>   <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>groupId</groupId>
>       <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
>       <type>test-jar</type>
>       <version>version</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>   
>   </dependencies>
>   ... 
> </project>
> ```
>
> Note: The downside of this solution is that you don't get the
>   transitive test-scoped dependencies automatically. Maven only resolves
>   the compile-time dependencies, so you'll have to add all the other
>   required test-scoped dependencies by hand.

Comment: Thank you, solved it by making my own FooBarFactoryForTest in my module